# Table's overflow-x inside fieldset

Tags: html, css, overflow

Here is two samples:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="gridwrapper">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8wzLzf09/1/

Overflow-x works correctly when table's parent div inside another div

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div class="gridwrapper">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>     
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8wzLzf09/2/

Overflow-x doesn't work correctly when table's parent div inside fieldset, it allows to expand table's width

What the reason of it? Anyone have idea how to fix it?

I need 100% width of fieldset and gridwrapper, size must be based only on main content-wrapper

Thanks

Comment: you can achieve this using jquery http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/eg4tw/3/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes there can be a lot of divs inside main content-wrapper, like this http://jsfiddle.net/eg4tw/5/ is it possible to do this with out using jquery?

Comment: m not sure about css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to min and max width on fieldset too, so this should do the job:

```
.gridwrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.content-wrapper, fieldset {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Based on clarifications, here is another attempt:

```
.content-wrapper {
min-width: 200px;
max-width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow-x: scroll;
}
.gridwrapper {
border: 1px solid #000;
overflow-x: auto;
max-width: 350px;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need 100% of fieldset width, sometimes it can be smaller than main content-wrapper

Comment: Can you reiterate - do you need fieldset to be 100% of width of a content-wrapper? And do you need ability of a filedset to be scrolled vertically if wider than content-wrapper?

Comment: I need ability of a table to be scrolled horizontally when it expands out of gridwrapper, and when gridwrapper inside fieldset. Table must be 100% width of gridwrapper

Comment: The first solution looks better for a particular case, but it seems that the second solution is suitable for common cases, thank you!

Comment: This solution will yield a `.content-wrapper` that is always 400px wide, so the width is not responsive. See: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/nxzwgLh4/

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
.gridwrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-width: 350px;
}
.content-wrapper {
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
table {
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it.  Apply `display: inline-block` to `fieldset` and `.gridwrapper`, and `display: table` to `.content-wrapper`.  This will force the content
to compute a shrink-to-fit width.  You need to set a `max-width` value to `.gridwrapper` and make an adjustment for the padding and border width from the fieldset element.

This layout will shrink in width responsively if the table is narrow enough.

```css
.content-wrapper {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed red;
  display: table;
}
fieldset {
  display: inline-block;
}
.gridwrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  max-width: 372px; /* you need to adjust 400px for padding and border width of fieldset */
  display: inline-block;
}
table {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Fieldset legend</legend>
    <div class="gridwrapper">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Im a long enough column!!!</th>
            <th>Im a long enough column!!!</th>
            <th>Im a long enough column!!!</th>
            <th>Im a long enough column!!!</th>
            <th>Im a long enough column!!!</th>
            <th>Im a long enough column!!!</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Im a long enough cell!!!</td>
            <td>Im a long enough cell!!!</td>
            <td>Im a long enough cell!!!</td>
            <td>Im a long enough cell!!!</td>
            <td>Im a long enough cell!!!</td>
            <td>Im a long enough cell!!!</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```